# Sumar campo tipo Time(7) sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un campo DateTime llamado Entrada y otro campo llamado Tiempo tipo Time(7).

Quiero sumar todos los tiempos registrados en el rango de un mes, pero como un usuario registra mas de 24 horas al mes, por lo tanto el siguiente query solo me muestra hasta 10:59:09.0000 y cuando en realidad son mas de 30 o 40 horas en un mes que un usuario registro.

```
select ISNULL(CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', 
Tiempo)),'00:00:00.000')),'00:00:00.00') as [Total hrs x Mes] 
from Registros
where Entrada between DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
and DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))) and 
Nombre ='Nombre de persona'
```

Como puedo sumar mas de 24 horas?

Comment: El tipo time no soporta más de 24 horas. Considera usar otro tipo de dato como un integer para contar la cantidad de minutos, segundos o la unidad de tiempo que desees. Después puedes usar un DATEADD.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar la suma de tiempo que sobrepase las 24 horas, se tendría que mostrar en un formato de caracteres. Aquí dejo dos opciones para mostrarlo. Una es para mostrar la sumatoria en horas (hhh:mm:ss.mss), la otra es en días (d:hh:mm:ss.mss).

```
SELECT -- Obtener la suma del tiempo y reemplazar todo lo que está antes de los minutos con las horas totales.
       STUFF( CONVERT( varchar(23), DATEADD( MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', Tiempo)), 0), 121), 1, 13, DATEDIFF( HH, 0, DATEADD( Ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', Tiempo)), 0))),
       -- Concatenar los días con el residuo de tiempo.
       CONCAT( DATEDIFF( DD, 0, DATEADD( Ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', Tiempo)), 0)), ':', RIGHT( CONVERT( varchar(23), DATEADD( MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', Tiempo)), 0), 121), 12))
FROM Registros
WHERE Entrada BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) AND DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))) 
AND Nombre ='Nombre de persona';
```